# Is it good practice to make a view subview of the main view, not a view it visually lies upon?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uikit

Say in my view controller I have a custom `UIView` which holds certain area inside view controller's view. Let's call this view `viewA`. And I have a custom `UIView` called `viewB` which lies within the bounds of `viewA`. I used to think that `viewB` MUST be a subview of `viewA` simply because it lies within its bounds. But today I got into an argument with a colleague of mine, who said that `viewB` is not necessarily should be a subview of `viewA` but a subview of the view controller's view instead. What do you think? Is there a common rule regarding this issue?

Answer (score 3):

I think there is no such thing that viewB MUST be a subview of viewA simply because it lies within its bounds.

The view hierarchy is organized by UIView's array property subViews. Each subview has their own frame information to layout relative to parent's bounds. Overlapping is normal

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion it would depend on the usage of viewA and viewB. If you always want to position viewB relative inside viewA's bounds, or of if you always want to use viewA and viewB together with each other it would probably be simpler to add viewB as a subview. If you want to position and use these two views separately or if the positions  of these two views are not related per se I would say that they should be separate views.

In short, just because views overlap does not mean they belong together / that one should be superview for the other.

Answer (score 1):

`UITableViewCell`s subviews of `UITableView`, not because they are with the bounds of the `UITableView`, but they have internal connections.

In your case, you need to think whether `viewA` and `viewB` have some real relationships or just happen to be together. Maybe `viewA` accesses and modifies `viewB` a lot? Or `viewB` is an component of `viewA`? That's when you need to set `viewB` to be `viewA`'s subview.